# Wrapper for custom Content Part - Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

Using the Orchard admin I created a new Content Part called **'Spotlight Wrapper'** with 3 HTML fields. I then created a Content Type Called 'Template 1' and assigned **'Spotlight Wrapper'** to it. I then created a new 'Template 1' content item called 'Home Page'. I then created a file called Fileds_Contrib.Html-Spotlight Wrapper.cshtml to wrap each HTML field in the 'Spotlight Wrapper' with an  and this is working. I have now added:

```
<Place Parts_SpotlightWrapper="Content:before;Wrapper=Parts_SpotlightWrapper" />
```

And created :

```
Views\Parts.SpotlightWrapper.cshtml
```

in an attempt to wrap the entire 'Spotlight Wrapper' Content Part in a  but cannot seem to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You declared a wrapper which I guess would lead to circular reference, as you try to wrap the Parts_SpotlightWrapper shape with itself. **Wrappers are just separate pieces of Razor (cshtml) code that act as a parent for a given shape.**

To achieve the behavior you want you should create a separate .cshtml file (eg. MyWrapper.cshtml) containing the necessary wrapper HTML code and attach it to your existing part like this:

```
<Place Parts_SpotlightWrapper="Content:before;Wrapper=MyWrapper" />
```

The wrapper code could look eg. like this:

```
<ul>
    @Display(Model.Child)
</ul>
```

Btw - Try to look how it's done in [Orchard.Widgets](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f5c66fbc172f#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Widgets/Views/Widget.Wrapper.cshtml). There are two wrappers *Widget.Wrapper* and *Widget.ControlWrapper* that wrap the *Widget* shape. *Declarations of those are not inside the Placement.info file (as you did), but hardcoded in [Shapes.cs](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f5c66fbc172f#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Widgets/Shapes.cs) shape definition, though the final effect is perfectly the same. The technique with the Placement.info was just introduced later as a shortcut.*

HTH

Comment: The problem was this part was made using the CMS admin, not via code. If a part is created via the admin these conventions do not apply. I recreated the part in code and packaged it up then installed it into Orchard and that allowed me to use the placement.info file and over riding conventions. Thanks for the response!